# Decode koi8-r string and quoted-printable in java

Tags: java

I got a .eml file, and some attachments inside

one of attachments - is .rar file

I using Tika to extract this rar, but sometimes Tika cant correctly convert some names of files, for example - such a name

```
=?koi8-r?Q?6=5F=F4=ED=5F15=2E05=2Erar?=
```

So i was looking for an answer, how to convert such a string to correctly readed value

Is there any libraries in java, to do this?

I guess it happends cause string got `=?koi8-r?Q?` in the start, so maybe, if i convert string to something like this, i will get move convertable value, like this `6=5F=F4=ED=5F15=2E05=2E`, but if i will do so, i finnaly couldnt find a solution to convert

Does anybody know how to convert such a string correctly?

I spend a lot of time to make it, but still - no results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code

```
public class EncodingUtils {
    private EncodingUtils() {
    }

    public static String decodeKoi8r(String text) {
        String decode;
        try {
            decode = MimeUtility.decodeText(text);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            decode = text;
        }

        if (isQuotedKoi8r(decode)) {
            decode = decode(text, "KOI8-R", "quoted-printable", "KOI8-R");
        }
        return decode;
    }

    public static boolean isQuotedKoi8r(String text) {
        return text.contains("=") || text.toLowerCase().contains("koi8-r");
    }

    public static String decode(String text, String textEncoding, String encoding, String resultCharset) {
        if (text.length() == 0) {
            return text;
        }

        try {
            byte[] bytes = text.getBytes(textEncoding);
            InputStream decodedStream = MimeUtility.decode(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes), encoding);
            byte[] tmp = new byte[bytes.length];
            int n = decodedStream.read(tmp);
            byte[] res = new byte[n];
            System.arraycopy(tmp, 0, res, 0, n);
            return new String(res, resultCharset);
        } catch (IOException | MessagingException e) {
            return text;
        }
    }
}
```

And test:

```
public class EncodingUtilsTest {
    @Test
    public void koi8r() {
        String input = "=?koi8-r?Q?11=5F=F4=ED=5F21=2E05=2Erar?=";
        String decode = EncodingUtils.decodeKoi8r(input);
        Assertions.assertEquals("11_ТМ_21.05.rar", decode);
    }

    @Test
    public void koi8rWithoutStartTag() {
        String input = "=CF=D4=C4=C5=CC=D8=CE=D9=CD =D4=D2=C1=CE=DB=C5=CD =D2=C5=DA=C0=CD=.eml";
        String decode = EncodingUtils.decodeKoi8r(input);
        //Тут знак "=" вконце, это битые исходныые данные, если заменить исходную строку на =CF=D4=C4=C5=CC=D8=CE=D9=CD =D4=D2=C1=CE=DB=C5=CD =D2=C5=DA=C0=CD=C5.eml будет нормальное слово "резюме"
        Assertions.assertEquals("отдельным траншем резюм=.eml", decode);
    }
}
```

Good day!